# Basis dimension (k) low but unable to increase it

Tags: r, repeated-measures, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, basis-function

I have a GAM of the form:

```r
Abundance ~ Treatment + s(KelpCover) + s(DayofYear, by=Treatment)
```

Where `Abundance` is a count of individuals in a quadrat, `Treatment` has 3 levels, `KelpCover` is percentage of kelp covering the quadrat to the nearest 10%, and day of the year is the day the data was collected on. `KelpCover` has a non-linear relationship with `Abundance`, and I am smoothing `DayOfYear` by `Treatment` level to account for the repeated measures design of my study as suggested by [Mundo et al. 2022](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9844249/).

I am running into the issue that my k-index values are low (<1) and my k' and edf values are close to each other, indicating that k needs to be increased. The problem is that my data do not allow k to be larger than 9. Here is my model output as well as the GAM diagnostics and appraise output:

[image]
[image]

Visually, the smooth terms look to accurately capture the variation in the data, but the diagnostics are saying otherwise. Is this okay, or is there a problem with my model?

Comment: This doesn't look bad, but why wouldn't your data allow for a bigger k-value?

Comment: @LukasLohse Probably because the number of unique values of `Dayofyear` in the data is 9.

Comment: Yes there are only 10 unique day of the year values. So my k-index values being small and my k' and edf being close does not compromise my model fit?

Comment: Huh, so I played around with a few simulations, but i can't get k-indeces that small. Would you please share the plots you get from running `gam.check(M2)`.

Comment: Maybe it's some kind of interaction effect? Take a look a adding `ti(KelpCover, DayofYear)` to your model. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/smooth.terms.html

Comment: @LukasLohse I added the diagnostic plots to the question. As for an interaction term, ecologically it doesn't make sense to believe there is an interaction due to the short time period studied. Since this question I have looked at using a model of the form Abundance ~ Treatment + s(KelpCover) + s(DayofYear, Treatment) which seems to give better diagnostic plots but still low k-index values.

Comment: Maybe just make `Dayofyear` a factor instead?  That's an increase in flexibility with no decrease in degrees of freedom (I believe.)